# Is there a context in which a native English speaker would use the word "happen" with the preposition "with" and "for"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Is it possible to use happen with *"with"* and *"for"?* For example, can I say the following?

> I don't know how I pulled it off. It just happened **for/with** me.

Comment: It is certainly possible in a different context: **happen for a reason** - **may happen with me at the helm**. It might be grammatical but it would NOT be idiomatic in the context you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

> It just happened for me.

Is totally natural, common use, despite the comment indicating otherwise.

You even have the connotation of the phrase correct — if you didn't say "I don't know how I pulled it off..."  it would still sound like you're not sure why or how it happened.  It "just did".